# PHP: Can't find key in Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a problem with my script over here.
I have got this array:

```
Array
(
    [KUNDENNUMMER] => 
    [BEZ] => 
    [DATUM] => 2014-10-10
    [VON] => 11:10:36
    [BIS] => 11:48:11
    [TAETIGKEIT] => Berufschule
    [BEZ_01] => 
    [DAUER] => 0001-01-01 00:37:00
    [STUNDEN] => 0.61
    [VERRECHENBAR] => F
    [BEMERKUNG] => 0x000c5cf2000000ba
    [USER_BEZ] => Armani, Kia
    [TZ_BEZ] => 
    [TT_VERRECHENBAR] => F
    [TT_ID] => 80
)
```

I want to echo "Cake" when $row (the array) [TAETIGKEIT] == Berufschule using this code

```
if(strpos($row['TAETIGKEIT'], 'Berufschule') === true) echo "Cake";
```

But the echo never gets called.
I also tried to compare directly

```
if($row['TAETIGKEIT'] == 'Berufschule') echo "Cake";
```

but it did not work either.
When I do

```
print_r($row['TAETIGKEIT'];
```

it prints

```
Berufschule
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `var_dump($row['TAETIGKEIT'], urlencode($row['TAETIGKEIT']));` output?

Comment: Maybe the value has preceding spaces? Try `if(strpos(trim($row['TAETIGKEIT']), 'Berufschule') !== false) echo "Cake";`

Comment: That makes no sense. Trimming does nothing but change the value of `strpos` to *another* integer.

Comment: @KiaArmani and if you had used `var_dump` you would have seen spaces in the string if any, regardless `strpos` would still have found the string so it doesn't really make sense that using `trim` worked as the latter parameter is what it would search for.

Comment: @h2ooooooo That's right, but `" Berufschule"` can't be found in `"Berufschule"`. ;)

Comment: @Paul The *second* parameter is the word to search for (it goes *haystack*, *needle*). [See this demo for why it would not make a difference](https://eval.in/205343).

Comment: That's the mean thing about PHP, I always get mixed up with the parameter order since it's not standardized throughout the language. You are absolutely correct.

Comment: Yeah, it's a huge mixup of conventions. Luckily my IDE has a "quick documentation lookup" to avoid using the manual constantly. It still makes no sense that trimming the haystack somehow found the match, though.

Comment: Edited my answer to summarize the issues.

Comment: I still do not understand. Does the OP trimmed the needle?

Comment: He didn't trim neither. In his first line, he uses `strpos` incorrectly, the second line probably fails due to a space in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For summary, code in question didn't work for various reasons presumably.

I can only assume, that the value of `TAETIGKEIT` has either a trailing or preceding space.

```
if(strpos($row['TAETIGKEIT'], 'Berufschule') === true) echo "Cake";
// doesn't work since strpos returns an integer if string is found or `false` if not.
// it never returns true

if($row['TAETIGKEIT'] == 'Berufschule') echo "Cake";
// doesn't work due to the superfluous space, thus it's not exactly the same
```

Solutions would be to use strpos correctly

```
if(strpos($row['TAETIGKEIT'], 'Berufschule') !== false) echo "Cake";
```

Or trim the values before comparison

```
if(trim($row['TAETIGKEIT']) == 'Berufschule') echo "Cake";
```

And as noted by [h2ooooooo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/247893/h2ooooooo), `var_dump` would show these addtional spaces.

Answer (score 0):

`strpos` never returns `true` - it returns `false` or integer value, so with `=== true` you will never get pass.

Just try with:

```
strpos($row['TAETIGKEIT'], 'Berufschule') !== false
```

Comment: @KiaArmani Your main problem is that `strpos` does not mean "bool isSubstringInString". It returns the index position of your match if it's found. Not `true`. `!== false` will only match if the substring was found.

Comment: if(strpos($row['TAETIGKEIT'], 'Berufschule') !== false) echo cake; does not print cake for me.

Comment: I think is an example where type coercion is actually the only solution.